# Android get Software keyboard events

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I am working on an Android Application, According to the requirements. I have to log every single key like backspace, alphabets, special characters. For doing this, I am using an EditText with 0 width so that it isn't visible. Here's the code:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText" />
```

In my JAVA class, I am requesting focus on EditText on a button press and then showing software keyboard through this code:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput (InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

And for getting inputs, I am using TextWatcher as below:

```
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {   before = charSequence.toString();
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {     Log.e("TAG","ON_CHANGE: "+charSequence);
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    String after = editable.toString();
    if(before.length()>after.length())
    {   Log.e("TAG","BACKSPACE");
    }
    else if(before.length()<after.length())
    {   Log.e("TAG",after.charAt(after.length()-1)+"");
    }
    else
    {   Log.e("TAG","NO CHANGE");
    }
}
```

Now the issues with this methods are as below:

1. When length of the EditText String is 0, backspace event cannot be captured.
2. Only Single character is important for me, however TextChanging event works on entire string.

Is it possible to get Software keyboard events in same manner as that of AWT listeners, like key up/down events.

Comment: Probably not; you're making too many assumptions about the keyboard.  What about voice typing? Or swiping?

Comment: Get rid of the `EditText` and use `onKeyDown()` and `onKeyUp()` of your activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare onKeyDown() and onKeyUp() are not called when I type.

Comment: @SLaks Wont be helpful here, think of like events in a game. Where every keypress is identified uniquely